# Deploy Heroku: when manage.py and settings.py file is in outside of app folder

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, deployment, otree

I have folder map looks like this:
``
C:\Users\OS\oTree

```
- oTree 
      |
      |-- nar2020 (this is the name of my app)
      |     |
      |     |--  templates.
      |     |
      |     |-- _init_.py
      |     |
      |     |-- models.py
      |     |
      |     |-- pages.py
      |     |
      |     |-- Procfile
      |     |
      |     |-- requirements.txt
      |     |
      |     |-- runtime.txt
      |
      |-- init_.py
      |
      |-- manage.py
      |
      |-- settings.py
      |
      |-- requirements_base.txt
```

(This is the standard format of Otree, if I move manage.py or settings.py into <*nar2020*> folder. the app cannot run in local host. And if I move Procfile, requirements.txt or runtime.txt to the outer folder (otree). I cannot push it in Heroku.So I cannot change the directoy of these files although I know that manage.py should be in the same folder with Procfile.

**My manage.py file**

```
 import os

 import sys

 if __name__ == "__main__":

   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

   from otree.management.cli import execute_from_command_line

   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv, script_file=__file__)

 django.setup()
```

**My Procfile**

`web: gunicorn oTree.manage:app --log-file –`

**My settings.py**

```
from os import environ

SESSION_CONFIG_DEFAULTS = {
    'real_world_currency_per_point': 1.00,
    'participation_fee': 0.00,
    'doc': "",
}

SESSION_CONFIGS = [
    {
        'name': 'nar2020',
        'display_name': "nar2020",
        'num_demo_participants': 1,
        'app_sequence': ['nar2020'],
    }
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

REAL_WORLD_CURRENCY_CODE = 'EUR'
USE_POINTS = False

ROOMS = [
    {
        'name': 'nar2020',
        'display_name': 'Room for live demo (no participant labels)',
    }
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_LEVEL = environ.get('OTREE_AUTH_LEVEL')

ADMIN_USERNAME = 'admin'

ADMIN_PASSWORD = environ.get('OTREE_ADMIN_PASSWORD')

DEBUG = (environ.get('OTREE_PRODUCTION') in {None, '', '0'})

SECRET_KEY = bla_bla_key'

INSTALLED_APPS = ['otree']
```

With this directory, I push to heroku with the directory is:"***C:\Users\OS\oTree\nar2020***" and it deployed.

But when I run `*heroku run otree resetdb*`

*I got error as "cannot find oTree settings. Please cd to your oTree project folder, which contains a settings.file."*

When I run `*heroku run python manage.py migrate*`

*I got error as "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2: No such file or directory]*

As I may understood, because when I deploy heroku `git push heroku master` with the directory is C:\Users\OS\oTree\nar2020 while the manage.py and setting.py are actually in C:\Users\OS\oTree (outside of the app folder) so it has errors. But I don't know how to make Heroku understand it. All of the case I found here is when manage.py and settings.py are in the lower level of the app. but I don't know how to solve with my case.

I tried

1. `heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=oTree.settings`. (But of course it does not work)
2. I try to cd the directory back to ***C:\Users\OS\oTree*** and run `* heroku run python manage.py migrate*`. But I got the same error.
3. In manage.py file. I move `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")` out of  `if __name__ == "__main__":` => does not work

I stuck with them for many days. This is the first time I try to deploy Otree app on heroku. Could somebody help me to set the directory for setting.py file and manage.py file?